# VBA userform_Get Value from additional textboxes to cells

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I don't know how to take action with the VBA Userform here.

I have a userform which allows users add more textboxes and type the value to the textboxes. I want to copy those values from each additional textbox to separate cells. This is what I did, but not working.

**Label "Add textbox after clicking_THIS ONE IS WORKING"**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  x = Me.Controls.count + 1
  Set xx = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "CtrlName" & x)
  xx.Top = x * 20 - 108
  xx.Left = 396
  xx.Width = 288
End Sub
```

**Label "Get value from textboxes to cell_THIS IS NOT WORKING"**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim count as Integer
  Dim i as Integer
  count = Me.Controls.count - 9 ("I have 9 other controls, so need to - 9 to count the number of textboxes")
  For i = 1 To count
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
  Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is the `Me.Controls ("TextBox" & I).Value`. I tried different funtions here, but still couldn't solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your textboxes `CtrlName10`, `CtrlName11`, etc. You must use *those* names, not `TextBox1` etc. Which means that the value is `Me.Controls("CtrlName" & (i + 9)).Value`.

Hint: In error box saying *Could not find the specified object* press the button `Debug`. This will return you to the code editor, with the offending statement highlighted, and you can examine the variables in the Locals pane (on the View menu).